# Start Programming on Android 2.3

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, tablet

I program in Asp.Net, C#, and I have recently bought a tablet with android 2.3. I want to program some applications for my tablet but I see that it can be programmed only with Java. Does anyone know if I can program in C++? Is Qt available for it like it is in Linux? I've heared that it is possible but no one can give me any information. If it can't be done can anyone post me some links with Base Android 2.3 programming, but not base Java programming? I know Java but I prefer C++.

Comment: Note that C++ is very different from C#. The ideology of Java, in fact, is much closer to that of C# than to C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish Android went with Python myself. But Java is really the way to go, atleast for the UI parts of the program.  There is the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) that allows you to write in C or C++, but it is *not* just for writing applications. It's for the *performance critical* parts.  And unlike most suggestions to stay in a higher level language, it really makes sense here.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing better than the official documentation that you can find here: http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) as pointed out is quite good. You can certainly write applications in C++ via the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html), but outside of games, it's not the norm. You can't use QT. For drawing you would have to use OpenGL which while powerful doesn't give you anything in terms of controls or windowing.

I would highly recommend that unless you're planning to do games, you seriously consider using Java and learning the standard Android views, layouts and widgets. If you're interested in using C#, you can look at [Mono for Android](http://android.xamarin.com/) but it's not free, and it's not like you can use WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to take your Android development seriously, then I would recommend you a great book Hello, Android: Introducing Google's Mobile Development Platform:

http://pragprog.com/book/eband/hello-android

And - of course, the official Google documentation in connection with this site:)

Do not even think about something else then Java and ADT Plug-In for Eclipse, otherwise you will be beating your head against the wall and finally fail...

Answer (score 0):

A page for the Qt on Android project can be found at http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Necessitas

You can further be expecting some videos to be released from the recently completed Qt Developer Days in Munich, where there were a couple of talks on the topic :) (i will try and update this answer with links once those videos are made available, which hopefully will be soon). Slides without chatting and live demos are available at the end of this blog entry: http://cutehacks.com/2011/10/28/devdays2011/

As for actually writing the applications, just write them like any other mobile Qt application, using Qt Quick and suchlike - i'm told that with the recently released alpha3 the entire stack is now working, including Qt Mobility.